# Best way to append in array field instead of override in nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to append data in array field instead of override.

My association is User has one preference

In **preferences** table I have two array field

**profile_preferences** array of integer
**group_preferences** array of integer

What I want to achieve is I want to append data in profile_preferences and group_preferences field instead of override

The way I am doing is like below

```
Class PreferencesController < ApplicationController

  def update
    if current_user.update(preference_params)
      update_profile_preferences
      update_group_preferences
      render json: { success: true }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { error: "#{current_user.errors.full_messages}" }, status: 400
    end
  end


  private
  def preference_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, preference_attributes: [:id, :phone_number, :title, :profile_preferences => [], :group_preferences => [], :friends => [], :sales => []])
  end

  def update_profile_preferences
    preferences = preference_params.try('[]', "preference_attributes").try('[]', "profile_preferences")&.map(&:to_i)
    ###Below I need to reload the object otherwise it is not working 
    preferences += current_user.preference.reload.profile_preferences if preferences.present?
    current_user.preference.update_attributes(profile_preferences: preferences) if preferences.present?
  end

  def update_group_preferences
    group = preference_params.try('[]', "preference_attributes").try('[]', "group_preferences")&.map(&:to_i)
    group += current_user.preference.reload.group_preferences if group.present?
    current_user.preference.update_attributes(group_preferences: group) if group.present?
  end

end
```

Params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/Vu86W4ydQ11iZ/WFEvn3QkxrOkkUtCq+asjdkaslkjadlkalksdk/uS1erNIwg==", "user"=>{"preference_attributes"=>{"friends"=>["50587"], "profile_preferences"=>["50586", "50588"], "group_preferences"=>["4", "2", "5"], "id"=>"778"}}, "first_name"=>"ssss", "last_name" => "jsjjj"}
```

Is there any better way to achieve this?

**Note**: I am using jquery ajax to send form data

Comment: it is a headache, you need to update them manually, like `user.preferences.profile.push("123")` we used the approach to send the complete json from frontend with old and new values in the same param so doing a simple update works without anything new to do, so if you have that option as it's not complicated on frontend you will have your backend clean

Comment: @xploshioOn If I send old and new values in the same params then how it will update automatically?

Comment: let me explain more, you have on your database `column1 = [1,2]`, in your front you ask for this information and you want to add 3 to that column so then you send back to your server `{column1: [1,2,3]}`, and if you do something like `Model.update(params)`, column will be replaced in theory but with the complete value so it doesn't matter

Comment: okay got it. Basically you are merging the old and new params at the front end layer

Comment: exactly so you don't have to worry for special case if there is an array or json on your params

Comment: Yeah I got it but in my case I won't get old column values so I need to do the way I am doing. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: This is a typical quandry for complex column types. I would create a `user_preferences` join table and take advantage of the ActiveRecord methods that come with the `has_many :through` construct.